# Xcode 8 Automatic provisioning failed issue

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am trying to test my app on a new device.
I am trying to automatically manage signing on Xcode and the Provisioning Profile is selected to "Automatic" in Build Settings.

However I am getting the following error:
[image]

Anyone know what I might be missing?

I have selected my personal team too, it is just not shown in the screen shot here(redacted)

**UPDATE**

Few things that might help:

1. I do not currently have a paid membership(it expired 2 weeks back).
2. Account settings are correctly configured in Preferences.
3. I am successfully able to run on another device which I have used in the past with my paid developer account.

Comment: Do you have a paid membership?  Have you already registered 100 devices?  Are your account settings correct in the "Accounts" preferences in Xcode?

Comment: updated the question with answers to your questions.

Comment: @Paulw11 And I have not registered 100 devices with my account.

Comment: If you don't have a paid membership then you can't register any more devices against your profiles. Your other devices are already in the profiles so you can run on them.

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh did not know that. Is there a way that I can remove the previous device, so a new one can be added?

Comment: I don't believe so.  You could set up a new, free membership with a different Apple ID in order to test on this device only, but it wouldn't let you test on your other devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have an active, paid, subscription to the Apple Developer program then you cannot add additional devices to your provisioning profiles.

Any devices that have been previously registered against your membership will continue to work until those provisioning profiles expire.

Comment: I am getting this same error. Though I do not have any subscription to Apple development program, I was able to test my app on two to three devices. But trying to run it on yet another device stopping me with this error. Is there any limitation to do this?